# I have problem in set alert condition in pine script code

Tags: pine-script

```
alertcondition(longCondition, title="Buy Alert", message="BUY" )
alertcondition(shortCondition, title="Sell Alert", message="SELL" )
```

in above code i need to change

1. Buy alert once per bar.
2. No more Buy Alert till Sell Alert trigger.
3. and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

You should record the state of your trade and then decide to alert or not.

```
var TradeLongOn = true // If you set this to false, no one trade will occur
var TradeShortOn = false
TriggerAlertLong = false
TriggerAlertShort = false
if longCondition and TradeShortOn
    TradeShortOn := false
    TradeLongOn := true
    TriggerAlertLong := true
if shortCondition and TradeLongOn
    TradeLongOn := false
    TradeShortOn := true
    TriggerAlertShort := true
alertcondition(TriggerAlertLong, title="Buy Alert", message="BUY" )
alertcondition(TriggerAlertShort, title="Sell Alert", message="SELL" )
```